How should I go about scaling custom JComponents that have a fixed size based off its painted image?
I have completely custom state based buttons that paint a background image based off of its current state. It extends JComponent. When it’s clicked or the cursor hover aboves the button, the button image changes accordingly. The image assets have a fixed size, thus the button has a fixed size as well. The problem I have is my button assets are designed with my 4k screen, and are ginormous on a 1440p or 1080p screen. I can scale the assets at runtime for a specific resolution, but that takes time and is expensive, and can also introduce artifacts. Is there a way to scale the whole UI based off of the screen resolution, or should I create new assets for different resolutions and make use of MultiResolutionImage?
I am trying to determine the correct and performant route I should take. Obviously forcing a UI that looks small on a 4k screen but oversized on a 1080p screen is not ideal.
I have tried scaling my assets at runtime based off the primary display resolution but it takes a lot of time with the amount of assets I have, and seems to be convoluted.

"I can scale the assets at runtime for a specific resolution, but that takes time and is expensive" This doesn't sound like such an expensive operation. You can set UI scaling when you start the app using "-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2". Also some of the look and feels are HiDPI aware and will scale the UI for you. I think the FlatLookAndFeel is one such, but you need to include a library for it.

@matt I am not using a look and feel, unfortunately. The UI of my application mimics the internal UI of a video game, and because of this requirement, I have designed a lot of stuff from the ground up. The uiScale option also did not work in my case.

If the UI scale option doesn't work, can you include an example? Also, if you have a a graphics, you can pretty easily set a affine transform that will scale the scene. Eg. You could grab information about your resolution, then set an affine transform that you will always use when painting your components. I would be surprised if it adds any significant overhead. With an example, this could be an interesting question.

@matt I may be able to mock up a video demonstration of the issue. I am not sure how I would post a functional code example without the assets and other parts.

@matt I suppose scaling the assets based of the resolution during application startup isn’t a huge problem.  The scaling occurs once. If the quality is good I may just have to do that.

If you don't want to share you're assets you can use a URL from the web. It should be something simple, that uses the techniques you're using. It could just be a small image that you display the same way you do in your app.
